# Select input is empty

Tags: php, html, forms

People can select their graduation year from a selection input. I email their selection to myself. However, based on the fact that nothing is printing to the console, the `$_POST["year"]` must be empty, which is why no year is actually being sent to me as shown in the pic below. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
<div class = "mailInput"> Year: 
       <div class = "select" name = "year"><select>
             <option value="2017">2017</option>
             <option value="2018">2018</option>
             <option value="2019">2019</option>
              <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select> 
       </div>
</div>

// Assign year input to year variable
if (!empty($_POST["year"])) {
     $year = $_POST["year"];
      echo("<script>console.log('Year after: ".$year."');</script>");
}
```

Comment: probably `echo $name;`? what problem you are facing here BTW?

Comment: What is the error you are facing ??

Comment: print_r($person) ? Its not working ? Or some other issue, tell us what exactly error or issue you are facing

Comment: ohh opps nvm, I asked a question before running my code- I edited my question with an actual issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written wrong html code,

```
<div class="mailInput"> Year: 
       <div ><select class="select" name="year"> // this line
             <option value="2017">2017</option>
             <option value="2018">2018</option>
             <option value="2019">2019</option>
              <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select> 
       </div>
</div>
```

You have given name to div element which was parent of select,
now above I gave name to select element.
Give it a try. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class = "mailInput"> Year: 
           <div class = "select" >
            //give name for select tag not for div
             //
                    <select name = "year">
                 <option value="2017">2017</option>
                 <option value="2018">2018</option>
                 <option value="2019">2019</option>
                  <option value="2020">2020</option>
            </select> 
           </div>
    </div>

// Assign year input to year variable
if (!empty($_POST["year"])) {
     $year = $_POST["year"];
      echo("<script>console.log('Year after: ".$year."');</script>");
}
```